# MS Project: Leveling subtask resources by moving summary task

Tags: pm-software, ms-project

I'm working on a microsoft project pro problem and need help.
I have two summary tasks A and B starting on the same day. Each Summary task has sub tasks 1,2 with resources allocated to them and obviously both subtasks 1 and 2 result in overallocation of the respective resources.

## A

#### ..1

#### ..2

## B

#### ..1

#### ..2

The timing of Subtasks 1,2 are ridgid within each Summary task. I want to resource level the subtasks to prevent overallocation but MS Project levels the subtasks by moving just the subtask.
How can I get MS Project to maintain the subtasks timing by moving the Summary task (i.e. all the subtasks within) to fix the resource overallocation. Example:

From above MS Project moves subtask 1 within the summary task B to fix the overallocation:

## A

#### ..1

#### ..2

## B

#### ....1

#### ..2

I want it to move the start date of the summary task to prevent overallocation like this:

## A

#### ..1

#### ..2

## ..B

#### ....1

#### ....2

I didn't think this would be a problem but have not found a way to do it yet...
Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

DO NOT HARD CODE IN DATES.  Remove your date constraints.  All leaf level packages should be "as soon as possible."  This way, the tool can move the packages based on leveling or actuals entered and whatever else.  The tool, as you have it now, cannot move the packages in the manner you want because of a constraint...most likely.

In addiiton, build the predecessor/successor logic in yourself.  Don't "level" the schedule by using the tool.  You lose too much control.  You'll end up burning a ton of hours fixing what the tool did because the tool is only so smart.

Finally, don't chase this concept of over utilized resources.  Obviously, you'd want to fix a resource that is showing 180% or higher.  But to chase these minor fluctuations is futile, especially after you enter in actuals.

Comment: Thanks for the note. All my starts are as soon as possible. My resources are machines so 100% really is the most that can be allocated. I've been at this for a whole day now and cant get Project to do what I need. Will have to write my own leveling functions in vba.